# Using LIKE in JOIN query if values for join are in specfic set

Tags: sql, join, hive

I have two sets:

1. dictionary of names
2. "names" extracted from emails

I want to find out if "names" from set 2. are similar/contains any of names in set 1 for example:

- johnsmith contains john so it will be ok.

How can I do this in HIVE SQL?

```
select a.*, b.name as name_from_email
from set2 a left join 
     set1 b 
     on a.email_name rlike concat('%',b.name,'%')
```

I got error:
" Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN ''%'':28:27, org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:323, "

Comment: I think Hive only supports equijoins, which is the root of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use instr like following:

```
on(1=1) where instr(a.email_name, b.name) != 0
```

I know this is painful but this will solve the problem

Cheers!!

Comment: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 3:35 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN '0':28:27,

Answer (score 0):

You can rather painfully do this to get matches:

```
select a.*, b.name as name_from_email
from set2 a cross join 
     set1 b 
where a.email_name rlike concat('%', b.name, '%');
```

Getting the additional non-matched rows in is a pain.  I think this should work:

```
select a.*, b.name as name_from_email
from set2 a cross join 
     set1 b 
where a.email_name rlike concat('%', b.name, '%');
union all
select a.*, null
from set2 a
where not exists (select 1
                  from set1 b
                  where a.email_name rlike concat('%', b.name, '%')
                 );
```

Note:  You may find that this compiles but does not actually run.